# Please upvote Community Promotion Ads - 2015

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

I just put in a promo ad for Trailhead today and saw that NONE of the ads that @AlexTennant put up in February had been upvoted beyond the single vote I cast for them way back then. You'll note the following in the [Community Promotion Ads - 2015](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/903/community-promotion-ads-2015/2031#2031) post where it says the following:

> There is a minimum score threshold an answer must meet (currently 6) before it will be shown on the main site.

Gang, we're missing out on promoting our community and Salesforce Developers in general by not upvoting Promotion Ads for materials related to us and what we do! Please take the time to click on the link I've provided to the post and upvote at least some of the promo ads and/or create some additional ones if you don't like what you see.

People have complained about how poorly Salesforce is perceived as a development environment in surveys, yet we're not making any effort to put out the information in our own community to help them realize how easy it can be to learn. Let's try to change that perception by casting a vote to get some promos in place about what we do and how to learn!

Comment: +1 for obvious reasons.

Comment: I just finished contributing another promo ad - one that links to the developer docs home page.

Comment: voted.. awesome work guys.. :-)

Comment: I see they've been putting some of them up now that are getting click throughs! Thanks to all who've responded and have been voting. We still have more that need votes so they'll get some use. I just added another you guys might like.

Comment: Where I can find those ads? I will upvote for sure!

Comment: @Ashwani. Click on the gold text in the post above. It's linked to the original post and will take you to where you can find the ads.

Comment: Added my votes, thanks for pointing this out I wasn't aware of it.